# Cannot Serve Static Files

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

Currently, sending a postman request out to my API on my static-file-serving route gives me a 404 error, despite me double-checking that I'm GETting from the right route. The server worked fine in terms of serving files before adding SocketIO. Unfortunately, even when I remove the flask-socketio middleware, I cannot get the files to serve. Currently, I haven't touched this route in a long time, so I'm not sure what exactly happened.

Previously, I didn't have the static_url_path and static_folder options set when initiating the flask app object. I just added them after reading up on some other answers, but I get a 404 regardless of their presence.

All my other routes are working as intended.

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/profile_pictures'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'}
app = flask.Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/', static_folder="/profile_pictures")

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

UPLOAD_FOLDER = './profile_pictures'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'}

#unrelated code

@app.route('/profile_pictures/<filename>', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def get_profile_picture(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename,  as_attachment=True)
```

Any insight as to what the issue may be is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is "/profile_pictures" folder on your computer? If it is not in the root directory, and is in the same directory as the python program, change "/profile_pictures" to "profile_pictures", or use the full directory.

Comment: do you get error mesages when you run it in console? Did you try to use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed ?

Comment: @Alexander Getting rid of the slash worked! Thank you so much, silly mistake but it drove me insane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being I set the UPLOAD_FOLDER directory to

`UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/profile_pictures'`

Where it should've been

`UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'profile_pictures'`

Thanks for the answer @ Alexander : )

Answer (score 0):

You don't need both `static_url_path='/', static_folder="/profile_pictures"` and `route` for static files.

Choose one you prefer to use and delete the other.

Or change the

`static_url_path='/', static_folder="/profile_pictures"`

into

`static_url_path='/static', static_folder="/profile_pictures"`

and static files can be accessed from both

`HOST:PORT/static/<filename>` and `HOST:PORT/profile_pictures/<filename>`.

The `static_folder` is basically for static files like `css`, `js` and `images`.
The `route` is for user to download files directly.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately didn't fix the issue but handy knowledge for future reference